# How to convert a 2 rows header into a single row header from a 'xls' file?

Tags: java, excel, string, if-statement, stringbuffer

I am trying create a header from an excel file which has the table headers on two different rows. I have to make a single header row from those two.

The approach i am following is i am appending a @ to the first header and trying to replace it with the second header value.

My excel file looks like this

```
 Bank   Positive    Name of    Local Approah
 Value  Customer    Civilian   Remote

 //some data
```

And here is the code I use

```
public List<String> processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " started");
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    List<String>firstHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>secondHeader =  new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>finalHeader = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            if(currentRow.getRowNum()==0 || currentRow.getRowNum()==1 || currentRow.getRowNum()==3 || currentRow.getRowNum()==2) {  
                continue;
            } else {
                Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);

                //inserting the alternate row into the text file to make a continues header
                if(currentCell.getRowIndex()==4 ) {
                    if(cellValue.equals("Local Risk")) {
                        row.append(cellValue);
                        row.append("@");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        row.append(cellValue);
                        row.append("@");
                    }
                }
                if(currentCell.getRowIndex()==5) {
                    if(cellValue.equals("rating")) {
                        row.append(cellValue);
                        row.append("@");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        int pos = row.indexOf("@");
                        if(pos >=0) {
                            row.replace(pos, 1, cellValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
            rows.add(row.toString());
        }
    }
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " completed");
    return rows;
}
```

Currently, I get this output :

```
Bank@Positive@Name of@Local Approah@
Value   Customer    Civilian   Remote
```

But my aim is to make

```
Bank Value Positive Customer Name of Civilian Approach Remote
```

Can somebody help me solve this?

Comment: @Sirmyself thanks, i have worked on the sheet and i have discoved something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External link for a fiddle :

[Here is a fiddle](http://tpcg.io/WpLKwr) I made with hard-coded data that uses pretty much the same algorithm than the bellow examples.

---

For the header, you would better make a list with the two rows and append the strings when you are done.

Try this code instead :

```
public List<String> processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    int rowCnt = 0;
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.getLastCellNum(); ++i) {
            Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);

            headers.add(rowCnt + (i * (rowCnt+1)), cellValue);
        }
        ++rowCnt;
    }

    return headers;
}
```

This algorithm will work for any number of rows and any number of columns, as long as the number of columns per row is the same. [here's a fiddle](http://tpcg.io/WpLKwr) with hard-coded example data that follows the same algorithm. When this is done, you can append the strings 2 by 2 (or 3 by 3 if the headers are 3 rows high). Something like this algorithm should be alright for that :

```
private static List<String> appendStrings(List<String> original, int group) throws Exception {
    if (original.size() % group == 0) {
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i += group) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < group; ++j) {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
                sb.append(original.get(i + j));
            }
            newList.add(sb.toString());
        }

        return newList;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("MyClass::appendStrings() ---> the group value must be a factor of the size of the original list");
    }
}
```

If your rows may contain empty cells and you don't want the empty string to be added, but still want to respect the order, you will need to remove the data after the list is generated. Like this :

```
public List<String> processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    /*... same code as previous example ...*/

    // the following removes all "" or null values
    while(headers.remove(null) || headers.remove("")){}

    return headers;
}
```

Comment: can u check my approach

Comment: @mandrek https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165001/discussion-between-sirmyself-and-mandrek

Comment: let continue on chat

Comment: can you look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810857/how-to-print-the-contents-of-stringbuilder-in-each-line-in-a-output-text-file-in/48811622#48811622

Comment: u dere ? please comment when you r in

Answer (score 3):

`row.toString().replaceAll("@", cellValue);` has no effect, because the string that you get after the call of `toString` and subsequent replacement gets dropped and garbage collected.

If you want to do an in-place replacement, use `indexOf` and `replace(int,int,String)`:

```
int pos = row.indexOf("@");
if (pos >= 0) {
    row.replace(pos, pos+1, cellValue);
}
```

In addition, the replacement has to happen when you are scanning a different row from the insertions of `'@'` characters, so you need to make sure that `StringBuilder` from row 4 "survives" when you go into row 5. For this to work declare `row` outside the loop, and replace it with a new one only when the current row is not equal to 4:

```
StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
    ...
    if (currentCell.getRowIndex() == 4) {
        continue;
    }
    if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
        rows.add(row.toString());
        row = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: not working i am getting Bank@   Positive@    Name of@    Local@ Approah@

Comment: @Mandrek Oops, I put `1` in place of `pos+1`, thinking that it's a length, not the end index. This should work after the edit.

Comment: @Mandrek This is really odd. Could you run this with a debugger and see that the code enters the `if (pos >= 0)` statement?

Comment: i have posted the completed code what i am using , is this line if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
            rows.add(row.toString());

 doing somthing wrong

Comment: @Mandrek Please see the edit, I think the reason this does not work is that the string builder gets discarded between rows 4 and 5.

Comment: i am getting this  

Bank@Positive@Name of@Local Approah@
Bank Value Positive Customer Name of Civilian Approach Remote
Bank Value Positive Customer Name of Civilian Approach Remote

Comment: @Mandrek Does the code enter `if (pos >= 0)` statement when the row is 5? That's the line that I think does not run. Once you figure out why, the fix would be complete.

Comment: @Mandrek then you need to figure out why it doesn't (did it reach `break` before entering? Did `pos` get a negative index back? What else did go wrong?)

Comment: @dasblinkedlight i am not sure why i am getting this type of output ?